# PHP Google Drive API installation and file upload

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, google-drive-api

Hi guys i'm trying uploading file trought G drive API.

Can't find out why it returns error:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Gdrive{

function initialize(){
$credentials = $this->GetOAuth2Credentials($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['credentials'] = $credentials;

}
/**
 * Exchange an authorization code for OAuth 2.0 credentials.
 *
 * @param String $authorizationCode Authorization code to exchange for an
 *     access token and refresh token.  The refresh token is only returned by
 *     Google on the very first exchange- when a user explicitly approves
 *     the authorization request.
 * @return OauthCredentials OAuth 2.0 credentials object
 */
function GetOAuth2Credentials($authorizationCode) {
  $client = new apiClient();
  $client->setClientId(Config::5112+++++.apps.****5971157@developer.gserviceaccount.com);
  $client->setRedirectUri(Config::site_url());

  /**
   * Ordinarily we wouldn't set the $_GET variable.  However, the API library's
   * authenticate() function looks for authorization code in the query string,
   * so we want to make sure it is set to the correct value passed into the
   * function arguments.
   */
  $_GET['code'] = $authorizationCode;

  $jsonCredentials = json_decode($client->authenticate());

  $oauthCredentials = new OauthCredentials(
      $jsonCredentials->access_token,
      isset($jsonCredentials->refresh_token)?($jsonCredentials->refresh_token):null,
      $jsonCredentials->created,
      $jsonCredentials->expires_in,
      Config::CLIENT_ID,
      Config::CLIENT_SECRET
  );

  return $oauthCredentials;
}
function SaveNewFile($inputFile) {
  try {
    $mimeType = 'text/plain';
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($inputFile->title);
    $file->setDescription($inputFile->description);
    $file->setMimeType($mimeType);
    // Set the parent folder.
    if ($inputFile->parentId != null) {
      $parentsCollectionData = new DriveFileParentsCollection();
      $parentsCollectionData->setId($inputFile->parentId);
      $file->setParentsCollection(array($parentsCollectionData));
    }
    $createdFile = $this->service->files->insert($file, array(
        'data' => $inputFile->content,
        'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));
    return $createdFile;
  } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
    /*
     * Log error and re-throw
     */
    error_log('Error saving new file to Drive: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);
    throw $e;
  }
}


}
```

when i invoke the initialize() method it returns error:

```
Message: Undefined index: code

Fatal error: Class 'apiClient' not found
```

what should be? i'm doing right in my code ? does i need more code to make it works? i created web application project on google api console.

need i to include google php sdk? in the google docs it is not mentioned for google drive api :/

Comment: `Config::5112+++++.apps.****5971157@developer.gserviceaccount.com` --- what's this? o_O

Comment: @zerkms is the secret code , but i used *** to hide the real code on stack

Comment: The class `apiClient` was not found. You probably forgot including the file it is defined in.

Comment: @Pekka's talking about the Google Client Library -- https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart#install_the_google_client_library

Comment: @Pekka yep but where is this php file? google doc doesn't says nothing about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of the PHP client library. Make sure you have the latest source and follow the instructions in the Google Drive SDK quickstart page to learn how to write a complete PHP app to upload a file to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

Comment: thx, now i'm seeing errors that i like, what about oauth i mean, i can't understand if for storing user's files i need their own approval or if i just need to approve with my own account (site api console account)

Comment: i'm on a web app which allows users to upload files, these files i would like to GET/POST on GDrive, so can't understand if users needs to log to google before the upload/download from Drive starts .. farei prima in italiano mannaggia.

Comment: i setted up an http://localhost/site redirect url in api console and then i use that in my script but it seems it doesn't works cause oauth url says the uri mismatch anyway :/

Comment: thx, checkout this maybe will be usefull to also other users and  for mesure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010680/google-drive-api-access-token-and-redirect-url-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
```

please use those require files and Google_Client().